# Renumbering and prefixing equations, figures, and tables in the last section

Tags: numbering, achemso

I'm writing a manuscript that will eventually be submitted for publication in an American Chemical Society (ACS) journal. For this, I'm using the [`achemso`](https://ctan.org/pkg/achemso?lang=en) document class.

Manuscript submissions to the ACS typically consist of two parts: a main paper and a file of Supporting Information (SI). Typically the main paper and the SI would be in separate .tex files, and output to separate .pdf files. However, I would like to *draft* the main paper *and* SI **in the same file.**

This may seem like an odd request -- what's wrong with two separate files? -- but having only one file for the manuscript drafting/preparation process would be helpful to me and my supervisor.

So, my questions are:

- Is it possible to reset to 1 the number counters for equations,
  figures, and tables **in the final section of my .tex file?**
- In addition, is it possible to prefix, with a letter "S", the number
  counters for equations, figures, and tables **in the final section of
  my .tex file?**

In other words, I'd like the equations in the Supporting Information (i.e., the last section of the file) to be numbered (S1), (S2), (S3), etc. Similarily, I'd like the figures in the Supporting information to be numbered Figure S1, Figure S2, Figure S3, etc. And similarily for tables: Table S1, Table S2, etc.

Here is my MWE, which makes use of the [`achemso`](https://ctan.org/pkg/achemso?lang=en) document class, along with a condensed version of its output:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape, detect-weight, detect-mode,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}

\author{First A. Author}
\affiliation[University A]{Department, University A, Address A}
\author{Second B. Author}
\affiliation[University B]{Department, University B, Address B}
\author{Third C. Author}\email{thirdauthor@univc.edu}
\affiliation[University C]{Department, University C, Address C}

\title{Article Title}

\SectionNumbersOn

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Methods}

\section{Results and Discussion}
% Equations in the main paper
\begin{equation}\label{eq:result1}
  \begin{aligned}
    A &= A_1 + A_2 + A_3 \\
    A_{\alpha} &= A_{\alpha 1} + A_{\alpha 2} + A_{\alpha 3}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:result2}
  \begin{align}
    B &= B_1 + B_2 + B_3\label{eq:result2:a} \\
    B_{\beta} &= B_{\beta 1} + B_{\beta 2} + B_{\beta 3}\label{eq:result2:b}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

% Figure in the main paper
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{A figure in the main paper.}\label{fig:result1}
\end{figure}

% Table in the main paper
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.2,table-number-alignment=left]}
    \toprule
    & {Quantity} \\
    \midrule
    Trial A & 1.11 \\
    Trial B & 2.22 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table in the main paper.}
  \label{tbl:result1}
\end{table}

\begin{itemize}
  \item REFER TO EQUATIONS: Refer to \cref{eq:result1}. Refer to \cref{eq:result2}.
Let's look more closely and refer to subequations: \cref{eq:result2:a,eq:result2:b}.
  \item REFER TO FIGURES: Refer to \cref{fig:result1}.
  \item REFER TO TABLES: Refer to \cref{tbl:result1}.
\end{itemize}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{suppinfo}
  Advertisement for, and description of, Supporting Information goes here.
\end{suppinfo}

\begin{acknowledgement}
  The authors thank funding sources.
\end{acknowledgement}

\begin{tocentry}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  Graphical TOC goes here.
\end{tocentry}

\clearpage
\section*{Supporting Information}
% Equations in the Supporting Information

% Figure in the Supporting Information
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{A figure in the Supporting Information.}\label{fig:si:result1}
\end{figure}

% Table in the Supporting Information
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.2,table-number-alignment=left]}
    \toprule
    & {Quantity} \\
    \midrule
    Trial A & 1.11 \\
    Trial B & 2.22 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table in the Supporting Information.}\label{tbl:si:result1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Change the format of the counter representations and reset them to 0.

```
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\section*{Supporting Information}
```

Here's a full example. I changed `[!h]` into `[!htp]` not only to avoid warnings.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape, detect-weight, detect-mode,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}

\author{First A. Author}
\affiliation[University A]{Department, University A, Address A}
\author{Second B. Author}
\affiliation[University B]{Department, University B, Address B}
\author{Third C. Author}\email{thirdauthor@univc.edu}
\affiliation[University C]{Department, University C, Address C}

\title{Article Title}

\SectionNumbersOn

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Methods}

\section{Results and Discussion}
% Equations in the main paper
\begin{equation}\label{eq:result1}
  \begin{aligned}
    A &= A_1 + A_2 + A_3 \\
    A_{\alpha} &= A_{\alpha 1} + A_{\alpha 2} + A_{\alpha 3}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:result2}
  \begin{align}
    B &= B_1 + B_2 + B_3\label{eq:result2:a} \\
    B_{\beta} &= B_{\beta 1} + B_{\beta 2} + B_{\beta 3}\label{eq:result2:b}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

% Figure in the main paper
\begin{figure}[!htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{A figure in the main paper.}\label{fig:result1}
\end{figure}

% Table in the main paper
\begin{table}[!htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.2,table-number-alignment=left]}
    \toprule
    & {Quantity} \\
    \midrule
    Trial A & 1.11 \\
    Trial B & 2.22 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table in the main paper.}
  \label{tbl:result1}
\end{table}

\begin{itemize}
  \item REFER TO EQUATIONS: Refer to \cref{eq:result1}. Refer to \cref{eq:result2}.
Let's look more closely and refer to subequations: \cref{eq:result2:a,eq:result2:b}.
  \item REFER TO FIGURES: Refer to \cref{fig:result1}.
  \item REFER TO TABLES: Refer to \cref{tbl:result1}.
\end{itemize}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{suppinfo}
  Advertisement for, and description of, Supporting Information goes here.
\end{suppinfo}

\begin{acknowledgement}
  The authors thank funding sources.
\end{acknowledgement}

\begin{tocentry}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  Graphical TOC goes here.
\end{tocentry}

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\section*{Supporting Information}
% Equations in the Supporting Information
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}

% Figure in the Supporting Information
\begin{figure}[!htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{A figure in the Supporting Information.}\label{fig:si:result1}
\end{figure}

% Table in the Supporting Information
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.2,table-number-alignment=left]}
    \toprule
    & {Quantity} \\
    \midrule
    Trial A & 1.11 \\
    Trial B & 2.22 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table in the Supporting Information.}\label{tbl:si:result1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]